# why is our Unity network object destroyed by client as it is instantiated?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the Server RPC is called is spawns a network object but on the client side the network object is instantly destroyed and we know this because it throws the network object destroyed by client error.

we checked and nothing in the code would destroy it we believe that we might be instantiating it wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate upon your question. What multiplayer solution are you using? Is it Photon? Mirror? or something else. Share code and the specific error you are getting.